# Django get model from serializer class from view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using **Django 2.x** and **Django REST Framework**

I have a serializer like

```
class DestroyAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model: User
```

and view

```
class DeleteAccountView(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = DestroyAccountSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self):
        # return self.get_serializer().Meta.model.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
        return self.request.user
```

I want to use the model defined in the view which is defined in the serializer. I tried with

```
self.get_serializer().Meta.model
```

But this gives an error

```
AttributeError: type object 'Meta' has no attribute 'model'
```

**How to get model being used by the serializer class in the view?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your syntax is wrong use --> **=** insted of **:**

```
class DestroyAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

refer [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#using-modelserializers)

Answer (score 4):

you can get model class by this syntext

```
model = self.serializer_class.Meta.model
```